# Why does this program print 0 instead of the specific set of values from a specified array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, initializer-list

I'd like to know why the `printf` function in this tiny program returns `0` instead of the array of numbers `3 2 2`:

```
int main(){
    int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};

    printf("first x, 2nd y, 2nd z = %d\n",mat[0][1][1]);
}
```

While working with X by Y matrices in C retrieving any value XxY was a breeze, but once I added another dimension I ran into this problem. I think I must've a misunderstanding of the way C deals with coordinates in arrays. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `{{3,1,1},{2,2,2}}` you initialize for a 2D array, not a 3D

Comment: It's C++ but it's the same principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

> int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};

you declare a 3D array but you give initialization for a 2D, the values are not placed where you expect

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};

  for (int i = 0; i != 2; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j != 2; ++j)
      for (int k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        printf("%d %d %d -> %d\n", i, j, k, mat[i][j][k]);
  return 0;
}
```

Execution :
    pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out

```
0 0 0 -> 3
0 0 1 -> 1
0 1 0 -> 1
0 1 1 -> 0
1 0 0 -> 2
1 0 1 -> 2
1 1 0 -> 2
1 1 1 -> 0
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Furthermore because your array has 8 *int* but the init value has only 6 the compiler initializes the two not specified entries with 0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this array element `mat[0][1][1]` does not have an explicit initializer. So it was zero-initialized.

Then you have such a declaration

```
int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};
```

then the first element of the array mat[0] as an aggregate is initialized by this list { 3, 1, 1 } and the second element of the array mat[1] is initialized by this list { 2, , 2, 2 }.

As for elements of the element mat[0] that are in turn aggregates braces are not specified then the elements of mat[0] are initialized sequentially like

```
mat[0][0][0] = 3
mat[0][0][1] = 1
mat[0][1][0] = 1
```

All other elements of the element (array) mat[0] are zero initialized.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[2][2][2] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};

    printf( "%d, %d, %d\n", a[0][0][0], a[0][0][1], a[0][1][0] );
    printf( "%d, %d, %d\n", a[1][0][0], a[1][0][1], a[1][1][0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you why your result is `0`:

```
int main(){
    int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
         for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
             for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
                 printf("mat[%d][%d][%d] = %d \n", i, j, k, mat[i][j][k]);
   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
mat[0][0][0] = 3                                                                                                          
mat[0][0][1] = 1                                                                                                          
mat[0][1][0] = 1                                                                                                          
mat[0][1][1] = 0                                                                                                          
mat[1][0][0] = 2                                                                                                          
mat[1][0][1] = 2                                                                                                          
mat[1][1][0] = 2                                                                                                          
mat[1][1][1] = 0
```

When you declare:

```
int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};
```

it means you are lying at program that it's 2D array, not 3D.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3-dimensional array, but you're initializing a 2 level array with 1 extra value. Consider something like:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
    int mat[2][2][2] = {
       {{3, 3}, {1, 1}},
       {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
    };

    printf("first x, 2nd y, 2nd z = %d\n", mat[0][1][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified an array with three dimensions, but only specified two. Furthermore, each element is supposed to have two entries, but you've got three.

If you [turn on warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) you should see warnings like these:

```
test.c:4:26: warning: suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]
    int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,5},{2,2,2}};
...more like that...
test.c:6:44: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
    printf("z for first coordinate = %d\n",mat[0][2]);
                                     ~~    ^~~~~~~~~
test.c:6:44: warning: array index 2 is past the end of the array (which contains 2 elements)
      [-Warray-bounds]
    printf("z for first coordinate = %d\n",mat[0][2]);
                                           ^      ~
test.c:4:5: note: array 'mat' declared here
    int mat[2][2][2] = {{3,1,5},{2,2,2}};
    ^
```

`int mat[2][2][2]` would initialize like this.

```
int mat[2][2][2] = {
    {
        {3,1}, {1,1},
    },
    {
        {1,1}, {2,2},
    }
};
```

You'll never get `3 2 2` from `mat[0][1][1]`. It will only ever return a single value. In this case, 1.

---

If you wish to store a list of 2 3D coordinates, use [2][3] instead.

```
int mat[2][3] = {{3,1,1},{2,2,2}};
```

Asking what z is for the first x and second y doesn't make sense. It's like asking what the altitude of Denver, New Jersey is (Denver is in Colorado). First x and second y are part of two different coordinates and have different z's.

Instead, you can get the z for the first coordinate like so.

```
printf("z for first coordinate = %d\n",mat[0][2]);
```

The first coordinate is `mat[0]` and its z is the 3rd attribute which is the 2nd index. `mat[0][2]`.